# Inter-dependencies between static libraries

Tags: eclipse, gcc, linker, dependencies, static-libraries

I am trying to link two libraries libA.a and libB.a along with a main.c file. libB has dependencies on libA, and main has dependencies on both.

I am able to compile the libraries independently, but when I try to link them together to create the final executable, I get the error that references to functions of A by B are not defined.

Is there any way to tell the linker to search for these functions in libA?

1. I am going to run this code on FreeRTOS on Cortex-M3 MCU so static linking is my only option.
2. I really want to be able to do this without changing the compile process for libB.

There is a similar question at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26619897/dynamic-linking-of-shared-libraries-with-dependencies) but as I said, dynamic linking is not an option.

**As requested by Ofek** a toy code 
(ignore functionality and syntax errors, if any)-

**libA**

```
int libA_fun1()
{ return stuff; }

int libA_fun2()
{ return something_else; }
```

**libB**

```
#include <libA.h>

int libB_fun1()
{
    //do stuff
    int x = libA_fun1();
    return something;
}
```

**main.c**

```
#include <libA.h>
#include <libB.h>

int main()
{
    printf("%d", libA_fun2() * libB_fun1()); 
    return 0;
}
```

I build libA.a and libB.a. Finally

```
gcc main.c -lA -lB -LPathA -LPathB
```

gives the error: undefined reference to libA_fun1 in libB_filexx.c, line xx

However, the function is properly defined in libA.h

Comment: This scenario is fully supported. Can you post the exact error message?  Even better - a toy code demonstrating the linkage error?

Comment: @OfekShilon - I have updated with an example

Comment: What you're doing, generally-speaking, should be perfectly fine (provided that there are no circular dependencies), so I'd look to build settings otherwise. This is a goofy guess, but I've been bitten before ages ago due to linker order. Try reversing the order in which you link `main` against `A` and `B`. Ex: `gcc main.c -lB -lA -LPathB -LPathA`

Comment: Hey guess what! That worked!! 
How?!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @Ike for suggesting a fix which worked.

## In short:

> If any [static] **library B** depends on symbols defined in **library A**, then **library B** should appear **first** in the list supplied to the linker.
> A more detailed explaination can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45135/linker-order-gcc).

The order in which librries appear to the linker is important too, and that is where my linking command was failing.